# break point not hit in ASP.NET web API remote debug in IIS

Tags: remote-debugging, visual-studio-2019

I have attached my Visual Studio 2109 debugger to the process with my web API published in IIS

[image: w3wp.exe]

But when I try to insert a break point

[image: break point]

"the breakpoint will not be activated currently. No symbols have been loaded for this document"

Any idea please?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution for the same type of error is that the build has "Optimize code" checked.
"Api project" > properties > Build > (select "Configuration" for the one you are debugging), make sure "optimize code" is unchecked.
If you changed it you need to deploy the project again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my webAPI is an ASP.NET Core 2 web API and in this case w3wp.exe is not the correct process. The process is the application itself. In may case api.exe instead w3wp.exe

thanks